# Checking for the existence of a folder in multiple-directories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple directories (which are not constant and the number changes dynamically) which has sub-folders. For any given sub-folder, I need to check if its present in any other directory. If so, I need to report it in the following format.

Please note that I am not worried about the contents or the size of the sub-folder while checking for the existence of that in another directory. As long as the sub-folder name is same in both the directories it needs to be flagged.

I tried thinking of using "os.walk" and "filecmp" in python but I was not sure how to control the dynamic nature of the input (ie., sometimes I will have 2 directories or 3 or more). Is there a more pythonic way to handle this efficiently ie., I am basically looking for suggestions on how to deal the following 2 issues effectively through Python,

- Need to dynamically determine the number of top level directories in the given path (eg. abc*)
- For doing the recursive check/comparison of a given sub-folder name in all the other top level directories (ie., taking all the sub-folders in "abc" and checking it against other folders and repeating the process again for "abc.prev" and "abc.prev.prev" directories)

**Directory Structure (in the form of tree)**

*Top level directories --> abc, abc.prev, abc.prev.prev

Sub-folders within each directory --> 1,2,3,4,5,6*

```
.
|-- abc
|   |-- 1
|   |-- 2
|   `-- 3
|-- abc.prev
|   |-- 1
|   |-- 4
|   `-- 5
`-- abc.prev.prev
    |-- 1
    |-- 2
    `-- 6
```

**Desired Output From The Code**

```
1: abc, abc.prev, abc.prev.prev
2: abc, abc.prev.prev
```

Comment: *Is there a more pythonic way* -  than what?

Comment: I have added additional notes in the question to state the exact problem

Comment: I would suggest using os.walk and a dictionary. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes dictionary will solve my first problem (ie., dynamically determining the number of top level directories). But then to compare the sub-folders against all other top level directories are you suggesting I create a "list" of those as values in dictionary and do a set comparison? For eg. if I have 4 top level folders I need to do this check 6 times right? (1 against 2,3,4 and 2 against 3,4 and 3 against 4)? I was hoping there will be a quicker way to achieve this.